# CoreData or Sqlite which should be used in iphone application for local storage of data

Tags: iphone

I want to develop an iPhone application. On which i have to use DB to store data locally.But i am confused about whether i should use Sqlite or Coredata.My application has a centralised database and i am taking data from that DB using Web service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sqllite works quite well and is what CoreData uses behind the scenes anyway.  But if you don't already know SQL, it can be complex to use.

CoreData is sort of easier to start, but complex to figure out how to work.  It performs better though.

In the end you are probably better off learning CoreData and proceeding that way.  Just don't do ANYTHING with CoreData in background threads until you are comfortable with how it works already, as that is a whole added layer of complexity fraught with peril.

Comment: I have a bulk of data to store since it is coming from web service and also i want to make relation between tables.Is it possible in Core Data?

Comment: Yes, you can define relations between objects.  Read a Core Data tutorial, or buy one of the many CoreData books.